# Power spectral density of the output of a linear time invariant system with a weakly-stationary process

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, self-study, stationarity, fourier-transform

Please note that I have **no background whatsoever in Fourier analysis and very little in time series**.

This is exercise 2.10 in Theodoridis' *Machine Learning*:

> Show that the autocorrelation of the output of a linear system, with impulse response $w_{n}$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, is related to the autocorrelation of the intput WSS process, via
>   $$r_d(k) = r_u(k) * w_k * w^{*}_{-k}$$

**I don't even know where to get started with this exercise. Here is the information I've gathered:**

**Some notation/terms to define**:

- WSS = Wide-Sense Stationary (or weakly stationary)
- $r_d(k) = \mathbb{E}[d_nd_{n-k}]$
- $r_u(k) = \mathbb{E}[u_nu_{n-k}]$
- $w^{*}$ means the complex conjugate of $w$ (*I think*)
- $*$ refers to the convolution sum. For example, if $\dots, w_0, w_1, \dots$ are parameters and $(u_n)$ a time series, $$w_n * u_n = \sum_{i=-\infty}^{+\infty}w^{*}_i u_{n-i}$$ I'm not sure how this works when you have two convolutions (**are convolutions associative?**).

It is worth noting that this exercise is used as an intermediate step to the proof of theorem

> **Theorem 2.1**. The power spectral density of the output, $d_n$, of a linear time invariant system, where it is excited by a WSS stochastic process, $u_n$, is given by
>   $$S_d(\omega) = |W(\omega)|^2S_u(\omega)$$

The proof is solved by using the result of the exercise above and then, apparently, using the "well-known" properties of the Fourier transform implying that

$$r_u(k) * w_k \mapsto S_u(\omega)W(\omega)$$
$$w^{*}_{-k} \mapsto W^{*}(\omega)$$

I opened one of my Time Series texts and found this theorem in the text by Shumway and Stoffer (4th ed.) on p. 175 (with very different notation), but I don't understand the proof, given my lack of time series and Fourier analysis background.

Could someone please assist with helping me start **exercise 2.10**, addressing my concerns in bold above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Show that $$r_d = r_u \star w \star \tilde w \tag{1}$$ where $r_d(k)$ is the autocorrelation function of the WSS output process, $r_u(k)$ is the autocorrelation function of the WSS input process, $w_k$ is the impulse response of the linear time-invariant system, $\tilde w_k = w_{-k}$ and
>   $\star$ denotes the convolution operator.

This is just a matter of massaging the sums involved and identifying the various components in the result.  Define the discrete-time autocorrelation function of the deterministic sequence $w$ as 
$$r_w(k) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty w_nw_{n-k} \tag{2}$$ which, since 
$w_{n-k} = \tilde{w}_{k-n}$, can be expressed in terms of $\star$ as
$$r_w(k) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty w_n\tilde w_{k-n} = w\star \tilde w$$ so that the result to be proven can be expressed as
$$r_d = r_u \star (w \star \tilde w) = r_u \star r_w. \tag{3}$$
Note that since $r_w$ is an *even* function -- we have that $r_w(k) = r_w(-k)$ for all $k$ -- the convolution $(3)$ can be expressed as
$$r_d(k) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty r_u(n)r_w(k-n) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty r_u(n)r_w(n-k), \tag{4}$$
that is, $r_d$ is also the *cross-correlation* of the functions $r_u$ and $r_w$.

Now, note that
$\displaystyle d_n = \sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty u_j w_{n-j}$
and so
\begin{align} r_d(k) &= E[d_nd_{n-k}]\\
&= E\left[\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty u_j w_{n-j}\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty u_m w_{n-k-m}\right]\\
&= \sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty E[u_ju_m]  w_{n-j}w_{n-k-m}\\
&= \sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty r_u(j-m) w_{n-j}w_{n-k-m}
\end{align}
The standard way of thinking of this double sum over $j,m \in \mathbb Z$ is that we first compute the inner sum (over $m$) for a fixed value of $j$, and then compute the outer sum (on $j$), that is, we work on column sums first and then on the rows of this infinite array. We get the same result if we *fix* $s = j-m$ and sum over all $j,m$ such that $j-m=s$, and *then* vary $s$; that is, we work on a *diagonal* of this array in computing the "inner" sum, and then sum over all possible diagonals. Thus we have
\begin{align}
r_d(k) &= \sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty r_u(j-m) w_{n-j}w_{n-k-m}\\
&= \sum_{s=-\infty}^\infty r_u(s)\left[ \sum_{j,m\colon j-m=s}^\infty  w_{n-j}w_{n-k-m}\right]\\
&= \sum_{s=-\infty}^\infty r_u(s) \left[\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty  w_{n-j}w_{(n-j)+j-k-m}\right]&\scriptstyle{\text{Now set}~t=n-j, j-m=s}\\
&= \sum_{s=-\infty}^\infty r_u(s) \left[\sum_{t=-\infty}^\infty  w_{t}w_{t-k+s}\right]\\
&= \sum_{s=-\infty}^\infty r_u(s) r_w(k-s)\\
\text{that is,}\qquad r_d &= r_u \star r_w,
\end{align}
thus proving $(3)$.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to the solution, basically you are missing one step.

Your linear system is defined by

$$ d(n) = u(n)*w(n) $$

Where $u(n)$ is a WSS. This means that the convolutions is how you model the effect of going through the linear system modeled by $w(n)$.

Now consider that the Fourier transform of a convolution in time is equivalent to a multiplication in frequency space.

$$ D(f) = U(f)W(f) $$

Being the $D(f)$ Fourier transform of the output

$$ D(f) = F \{u(n)\} $$

Consider as well that the Fourier transform of an auto-correlation function is the power spectral density.

Now, apply this principle to your equations above

$$ r_d(k) = r_u(k)*w(k)*w^*(-k) $$
$$ F\{r_d(k)\} = S_d(f) = S_u(f) W(f) W^*(f) $$
$$ S_d(f) = S_u(f) |W(f)|^2 $$

Reaching Theorem 2.1 and proving the equality right.

As for your question  **are convolutions associative** , I guess you meant linear: yes they are.

$$ (u_1 + u_2) * w  = u_1*w + u_2*w $$

Think of it as integrals, they are linear.

Comment: Sorry if this wasn't clear, but I'm looking for an explanation of exercise 2.10, not the theorem

Comment: The theorem is only stated to provide context.

Comment: I add another answer then.